# how to send integer as a parameter?

Tags: linux, unix, sh

I am not able to find why my code is not running. I am trying to send integers as the actual parameters to the add() function. As command substitution will substitutes the output of add() in the place of `add 5 6`.

```
#!/bin/bash

add () {
        echo `expr $1 + $2`
}

VAR= `add 5 6`
echo ${VAR:-"This is not defined"}
```

Comment: The only real reason to use `expr` is for regular-expression matching; prefer the arithmetic expression `$(( $1 + $2 ))` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a space after `VAR=`, you need to remove the space:

```
#!/bin/bash

add () {
        echo `expr $1 + $2`
}

VAR=`add 5 6`
echo ${VAR:-"This is not defined"}
```

Output is

```
11
```

https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varassignment.html

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space after `=` in your `VAR` command.

```
VAR=`add 5 6`
```

Comment: yes it worked now, thanks. can you tell why does unix shows this type of behavior ?

Comment: @vivekgupta This is the syntax Unix follows. You would need to re-search more to know why.